# Can I run Windows 8 dual boot on a mac using an external drive instead of having both OS's on the internal drive

Tags: macos, windows-8, external-hard-drive, multi-boot

Basically, I want to keep Mountain Lion on my MacBook Pro's hard drive only, I don't want to partition the drive to install Windows 8. I'm already using Win7 and WinXP in Parallels Desktop occasionally, but here's the deal. I am forced to use my Mac for work. I want to keep my personal and work stuff completely separate. My work requires the use of Windows, hence Win7 in Parallels. But it is not always efficient way to do things. What I am considering is this, if it works: I want to install Win7, preferably Win8 on an external drive, perhaps using bootcamp or some other method, so that I can boot my Mac to windows, and without sacrificing any more of my valuable internal hard drive space. Can this be done? If so, how?

Thanks,
David.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not easily or necessarily Microsoft supported and relies heavily on the differing and unvalidated advice of the user community and the level of effort required is maddening.

You will learn to appreciate your Para virtual machines performance vs trying to run a historically slow and aging OS from an external drive.

Windows 8 has a USB option but demands a USB 3.0 port.
Windows 7 has embedded versions that are as capable as the traditional version and the installation procedure is longer and complex since you build images.

The headaches and unsatisfactory performance of Windows from external media is one of the reasons people embrace Parallels, you complained about "inefficiency", care to elaborate ?